# Can users decide to target other users personally?

Tags: discussion

Not making any issue out here, but still want to ask this, that are users allowed to chat and target other users?

I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460077/php-remove-all-0s-from-start-of-string-could-be-an-unknown-amount/16460102#16460102)(Only +10K can see)

[image]

Just before 10 mins, a user downvotes my answer, saying that I am a repwhore and I shouldn't answer RTFM questions(Am not aware about RTFM, no user can go reading 1000's of meta question unless and until he is informed). Ok, I got his point, answer was not wrong, 12 users upvoted, I didn't went to those users for any upvotes, they upvoted themselves, moreover, I got another downvote in a minutes time, and I got suspicious, and went to chat, where people were discussing about this, so is this not against the rule? I mean if the answer should not be posted, **flag the mod**, why target me personally, let the mod decide what to do with the question/answers? They voted to delete the question, I don't mind and I don't care about rep, but this behavior seems unfair to me.

Straight from chat
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And we have downvote here too, I seriously don't understand this community

Comment: [Downvotes work differently on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Makoto I already told in my question, I don't need votes, I don't want downvotes either without any legit reason

Comment: I've added the link now.  It's not that there's not a legit reason, someone didn't agree with you. That's as legit as it gets in these parts.

Comment: The vote isn't targeting your personally. He's downvoting your answer because he thinks it's useless, not because of who you are. However, because of who you are (10k+) he thinks you deserve to be more ashamed for posting the answer, hence the comment.

Comment: I've voted to undelete. I don't see much difference between your answer there and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690477/73226) by the final delete voter TBH.

Comment: I don't think the person should have downvoted you for answering what he calls a "RTFM question" -- there is no thing as well-defined as such. He *should* have done what I just did -- find the dupe. (And then cast a close-as-dupe vote, or if not enough rep, flag a moderator).

Comment: @JeremyBanks I should be ashamed of what? Answering a correct answer?

Comment: @BenLee Thank you, I don't mind even if the question gets deleted, I've self studied everything, It's tough for me to learn things on my own and so I answer here so that I can learn more, this behavior hurts me, I mean we have so many restrictions that hardly we can answer any question, either its a duplucate, not constructive or not a real question, and we answer like this, and they downvote on no good reason, I can throw up 1000's of questions/answers here which are worst, but are still open

Comment: I would like to thank you for the support of other users, let the question get deleted or closed, atleast I got that I was not wrong here ..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why target you personally? Because you were the one that answered the question.

Did the answer merit a downvote? Of course not, it was correct. Downvoting for personal reasons is inappropriate. We cannot, however, enforce *why* people vote as they do.

I'd add that colluding to downvote enough to open up delete votes is counter to the spirit I'd prefer to see on SO. If there's a duplicate question it should be marked as a dupe and closed, and left at that.

Comment: Exactly, if it's a duplicate, mark as duplicate, if you find anything wrong, flag a mod, they are behaving as if they OWN the PHP tag...

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a fan of the **behavior**.  I'll admit that, the question does seem suspect, but whether you answer and whether people upvote for you is your and their prerogative, respectively.

Bringing it to the attention of moderators is the right thing to do, so they can decide what disciplinary actions (if any) need to be given out.

As for the *question*...I'm not sure about its quality (then again, I ran away screaming from PHP some twelve years ago), but the answers are decent, if not obvious.   I have to abstain from voting on the question since I'm biased, but I do feel that the answer's decent.